# Capybara-Poltergeist Angular modulerr on Linux

Tags: angularjs, linux, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I am experiencing some issue with Rspec & Capybara when trying to test my Angular application.

It returns me that error :

```
Failure/Error: visit '/'

 Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
   One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
   ...
```

Actually that error occurs only on TravisCI and my Ubuntu 14.04, everything is fine when running it on MacOS, or on both environments with Selenium instead of Poltergeist.
Setting js_errors on **false** leads to blank pages on Capybara screenshots.

Have you got any clue of what's going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're probably running different versions of phantomjs in your different environments.  Make sure youre running Phantomjs 2.1+ with angular apps, otherwise you're missing important functionality like Function.prototype.bind - The rest of the error message you get should explain whats missing.

Comment: Then specifying Travis to use PhantomJS 2.0 completely made it, thank you @Tom !   

For easy upgrade of PhantomJS on Ubuntu I used this npm command :    
`$ sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt ` 

Then in .travis.yml these statements :   
 
`before_install:
 - wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/travis-phantomjs/phantomjs-2.0.0-ubuntu-12.04.tar.bz2
 - tar -xjf phantomjs-2.0.0-ubuntu-12.04.tar.bz2
 - sudo rm -rf /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
 - sudo mv phantomjs /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`